# creating a json format file through SSIS

Tags: ssis

Right now my SSIS package creates a flat file in text format. But now client is asking to provide a file in json format. I am not sure how to place a file in json format. If anyone has this knowledge please share.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a valid JSON file: `{ data="your emtire CSV here"}` The customer needs to give you some idea of exactly what they want.

Answer (score 4):

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. It's an alternative to XML. Currently SSIS doesn't provide any kind of support for Json.

I am assuming that you want to create JSON file from database. SQL Server does provide nice [functionality to support XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx). You can convert your query result into XML format using `FOR XML AUTO` clause. There is third party class library, Json.NET which is a popular high-performance [JSON framework for .NET](https://json.codeplex.com/).

So get query result as in XML format, store it in variable, write a customer script where you can parse input xml into JSON and save result using Raw File Destination.

Have a look of below resources as well.

- [How to export data from database tables to an XML file using SSIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/635956/How-to-export-data-from-database-tables-to-an-XML)
- [Convert XML to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Samples.htm#)
- [Official Json.Net documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the late response. I will try these options.

Comment: Word of warning. The `FOR XML AUTO` clause does not fix invalid characters in the columns that are illegal in XML, so if you have any invalid XML characters you will need to handle this in the SQL query. The way I handled this was to use `REPLACE()` on columns that I knew contained invalid characters, although I'm sure there are other methods to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I did this.

V1
1) Data pump to file an XML query.
2) Use newtonsoft to convert XML file to JSON file.

V2
1) Use PowerShell, call the PowerShell from SSIS.
e.g.

`$Result = @()
    $commandSourceData = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQL, $sourceConnection)
    $reader = $commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()
    $Counter = $Reader.FieldCount
    while ($Reader.Read())
    {
        $tuple = @{ }
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Counter; $i++)
        {
            $tuple."$($Reader.GetName($i))" = "$(if ($Reader.GetFieldType($i).Name -eq 'DateTime')
                { $Reader.GetDateTime($i) }
                else { $Reader.GetValue($i) })";
        }
        $Result += $tuple
    }
    $Reader.Close()
    $Result | convertTo-JSON | Out-File $OutputFile -Force`